# how to iterate through a string and add a number for same letters in python

Tags: python

so I basically have this word and i am trying to figure out how to add a number a letter that is the same letter in the word.

sample text

> Books,
> Trees

sample output

> BO1O2KS,
> TRE1E2S

Comment: Please add the code you have written until now(your current progress)

Comment: i have not worked on the code yet i am not really sure where to start i just recently learn python so i am very new to this

Comment: Actually this seems to be a homework or test problem, so please read [Asking Homework Problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

string = 'Books, Trees'

def cvt(word):
    upper = word.upper()
    cnt = {k: 0 for k, v in Counter(upper).items() if v > 1}

    rtn = ''
    for x in upper:
        if x in cnt:
            cnt[x] += 1
            rtn += f'{x}{cnt[x]}'
        else:
            rtn += x
    return rtn

print(' '.join(map(cvt, string.split(' '))))
```

output:

```py
BO1O2KS, TRE1E2S
```